# Elasticsearch illegal_argument_exception error

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I'm working on a Rails 5.0.6 project with Elasticsearch 2.4. I'm using searchkick. My question is, I'm getting the following error when I try to reindex. (I understand some of the values in the error is maybe specific to my case)

`{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Mapper for [body] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [body] has different [index] values, mapper [body] has different [analyzer], mapper [body] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [body] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]"}`

What does this error mean, and what might be causing this issue? Then I can check the code and fix it.

I have found some articles on the web, but still not fully understand what causing the error.

PS: I've posted the same question on [discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-illegal-argument-exception-error/125110) too.

Comment: The most probable reason is that you have multiple types in your index and some of them have conflicting mapping definitions for the `body` field. This is not allowed. Either the `body` field in all your types have the same mapping or you need to split your types into different indices, which might probably be necessary once you fully migrate to ES 6

Comment: Hi sameera207. Your posts are a bit chatty for a 12K user, and I wonder if you could trim them down a bit? Signatures, thanks, advance thanks, please-help-mes and txtspk can all be removed - a technical standard of writing is preferred here.

Comment: Triple backticks are also not supported here - it's either single backtick for inline, or indent by four spaces for block.

Comment: hey @halfer, thanks for the edits. I thought having a little thank you is way of showing appreciation of the time someone had spend on answering a question. I've added a link from the discuss.elastic.co to this post.

Comment: @Val, thanks, I'll look in to the indexes 

Comment: The community would rather you did not add thanks and other chatty material. [This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) is a good resource, and [this one is also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). I would be obliged if you would read both - it would save me a great deal of time in the long run. As an experienced user, you are encouraged to read the Meta site generally, to get a deeper understanding of the netiquette that has formed around Stack Overflow.